# GRX Shifter with XTR RD

Tags: upgrades, groupsets

I have been searching all around and can't seem to find a clear answer to this. Will the GRX 400 shifters work with an XTR RD-M900 GS?

My thinking is that they will, but need to confirm. Seems like the GRX 400 is a rebrand for Tiagra 4700.

Comment: No, not without an ''adaptor''. Road has different pull ratios to mountain as of mtn 10sp and road 11sp (& 4700)

Comment: @JoeK how is that not an answer?   Please post as an answer.

Comment: @JoeK Talked with Wolftooth and confirmed. I need a Tanpan with a long cage on the RD.

Comment: Update... Got the derailleur and cassette installed. Didn't realize I needed a NEW cable for the Tanpan, so waiting for that to arrive. Also got a new chain with the quick release because I didn't want to mess with multiple new links. ANy how, got the derailleur adjusted using this video: [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZneCSSMPzc&t=49s).  Seems to be adjusted mostly right. I have the full spread, just waiting to get the chain and cable on to see if that puts enough tension on everything to get over the 42T Sprocket.

Answer (score 2):

As per Noise's comment Shimano road and mountain groupsets don't have the same pull ratios. You can mix road/gravel groups (e.g. 11-speed 105 with grx) if you wanted to add a clutched derailleur to your road group but in order to use a mountain derailleur with road or gravel brifters you will need a pull ratio adapter. Wolf Tooth makes the Tanpan.

Mixing road and mountain is also an issue for SRAM setups. Ratio makes and upgrade kit to use Eagle 12-speed derailleurs with 11-speed mechanical brifters (and use a wide range 12-speed cassette). Another option for SRAM is to use a Jtek Shiftmate with an Eagle (12-speed) derailleur and 11-speed wide range cassette.